# Ubuntu Unity Application Switcher shows second harddrive randomly

Tags: unity, 16.04, application-switcher

I'm using 16.04 Ubuntu Desktop

Sometimes, not all the time but I can't pinpoint what causes it application switcher shows my second hard drive among the applications. I made some research but either it's not a very common problem or I'm using wrong search terms.

I'm trying to take a screenshot of the switcher but couldn't figure out a way to both press prnscrn and alt-tab combination.

I have unity tweak tool and compiz config settings manager installed.